# I need help with balances

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct, balances

I would like to create a balance for each "vault". for example i will have my struct:

```
struct unnamed {
    string[] crowdFundName;   
}
```

I would like to add a balance to each vault for example crowdFundName[test] balance is x, crowdFundName[test2] is y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested mapping inside your struct for mapping different balances in it.
You can see this example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {

    struct unnamed {
        mapping(string=>uint) crowdFundName;   
    }

    mapping(address=>unnamed) _map;

    // Add crowdFund
    function addCrowdfund(string memory _nameDeposit, uint _amount) public {
        _map[msg.sender].crowdFundName[_nameDeposit] = _amount;
    }

    // Get specific crowdFund
    function retrieveCrowdfund(string memory _nameDeposit) external view returns(uint) {
        return _map[msg.sender].crowdFundName[_nameDeposit];
    }

}
```

Comment: Appreciate it and how do i link funds to diffrent crowdFunds ?

Comment: Instead 'msg.sender' that I put into two functions, you can add another input parameter with datatype 'address' and you'll replace msg.sender with it